# java regex fetch ip

Tags: java, regex, ip

How can i fetch `192.168.1.101` usin regex in java in following string ,however `Bcast` may be or not present

```
'      inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0'
```

with leading space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
(?<=inet addr:)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

I really feel Abhishek Simon's answer for the regex is an overkill. You are just extracting, not validating if it is a legal IP address!

For Bcast use something like below, obviously:

```
(?<=Bcast:)\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

To get all IPs, use without the initial lookahead.

You might be better of doing some string operations like splitting on  and `:` to get the IPs. I leave it to you to  decide.

Answer (score 2):

use `(([1]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])[.]){3}(([2]([0-4][0-9]|[5][0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))`

Here see this snapshot, it also fetches the bcast ip
[image]

Comment: thanx it worked, how can i fetch `192.168.1.255` - Bcast value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use: ([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})

The first tagged expression will be the first ip address that appears in the expression.

I often use [Regular expression test sites](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) to help troubleshoot regular expressions.